# Fabric plugin on Android studio fails to log in

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

This is the output from android studio.

```
    com.crashlytics - Crashlytics was unable to retrieve apps for projects. 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crashlytics.api.App.<init>(App.java:75)
    at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi.getApps(RestfulWebApi.java:601)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.PowerOnPage.getAppForProject(PowerOnPage.java:254)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.PowerOnPage.getProjectsWithApps(PowerOnPage.java:210)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.PowerOnPage$1.call(PowerOnPage.java:107)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.PowerOnPage$1.call(PowerOnPage.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Anybody else experienced this?

My system is:

Android Studio 1.2.2
Build #AI-141.1980579
JDK: 1.6.0_65
VM: Java
HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server 
VM  Vendor: Apple Inc.
OS: Mac OS X  Last
Action: Actions.Crashlytics.CrashlyticsAction

Comment: Mee too. Just yesterday everything worked for me.

Comment: I too am facing this issue. I've reported it on Twitter developers forum [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/unable-to-login-to-fabric-with-android-studio-plugin/43263/1)

Comment: @CosminRadu thanks for the forum link. Issue is resolved like twitter devs mention.